# Не могу понять как передавать сообщение на сервер средствами winsock2

Tags: winsock

Отправка сообщения

```
send(sock_, bf, sizeof(bf), MSG_DONTROUTE);
```

Чтение сообщения

```
len = recv(new_conn, (char *) b.c_str(), sizeof(b.c_str()), 0);
```

Почему сервер получает вместо сообщения которое я отправлял, какие то не ясные символы, да ещё так много. Как исправить?

Comment: с кодировкой что-то. шли латиницу проблем быть не должно. а проще всего использовать библиотеки, а не беркли напрямую, или вообще перейти на дотнет скажем

Comment: `sizeof(b.c_str())` - это вы так размер указателя вычисляете?

Comment: Благодарю да действительно дело было в размере указателя...  В место sizeof(var.c_str()) MAX_PATH использовал всё хорошо стало)))